# Testing structure in multi-module android application

Tags: android, kotlin, testing, mvvm, android-jetpack-compose

i'm a bit confused about testing in Android. I'm confused about e2e and integration tests and i don't know in which module(data,domain or presentation) should I place them.

As I understood, e2e tests that the whole system behaves the way it will be deployed. For example, verify that when I put valid credentials on the Login Screen it logs in and redirects to another screen. And, integration tests are focused to test the integration of different components, like a Repository interacting with a data source like a db or whatever.

So, I have doubts about when should I do a e2e or an integration test. Let's say I have a Login Screen, with a View an VM class. Should I create a different tests for the View (e2e expecting login behavior) and VM (integration expecting states update correctly and repository responds as expected), or just an e2e test checking that the whole login system works?

Also, I've been thinking on how I should organise all those tests in the different modules to

One integration test to verify that the use-case interacts correctly with a mocked repository

```
private lateinit var authRepository: AuthRepository
private lateinit var loginUsecase: LoginUsecase

@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@get:Rule
var mainCoroutineRole = MainCoroutineRole()

@BeforeEach
fun setup() {
    mockkClass(AuthRepository::class)

    authRepository = mockk()
    loginUsecase = LoginUsecase(authRepository)
}

@Test
fun `login with valid credentials returns user`() = runBlocking {
    val expected = User(username = "spozap", password = "P@ssw0rd!")
    coEvery { authRepository.login(expected.username, expected.password) } returns flow { Resource.Success(expected) }
    loginUsecase("spozap", "P@ssw0rd!")

    coVerify { authRepository.login("spozap", "P@ssw0rd!") }
}
```

Some unit for validation use cases:

```
private lateinit var validatePasswordUsecase: ValidatePasswordUsecase

@BeforeEach
fun init() {
    validatePasswordUsecase = ValidatePasswordUsecase()
}

@Test
fun `it returns validation error with NOT_NULL_FILLED code when empty password`() {
    val result = validatePasswordUsecase("")
    val expected = ValidationResult( successful = false, errorMessage = ValidationError.NOT_NULL_FIELD )
    assertThat(result).isEqualTo(expected)
}

@Test
fun `it returns successful validation result with no errorMessage when password is valid`() {
    val result = validatePasswordUsecase("P@ssw0rd!")
    val expected = ValidationResult(successful = true, errorMessage = null)
    assertThat(result).isEqualTo(expected)
}
```

And one UI test

```
private lateinit var navController: NavHostController

@get:Rule(order = 0)
val hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)

@get:Rule(order = 1)
val composeRule = createAndroidComposeRule<MainActivity>()


@Before
fun setup() {
    hiltRule.inject()

    composeRule.activity.setContent {
        navController = rememberNavController()
        AppTheme {
            NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = AppScreens.Login.route ) {
                composable(route = AppScreens.Login.route) {
                    LoginScreen(navController = navController)
                }
                composable(route = AppScreens.Home.route) {
                    HomeScreen()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Test
fun loginWithValidCredentialsRedirectsToHomeScreen() {
    composeRule.onNodeWithTag(TestTags.USERNAME_INPUT).performTextInput("user1")
    composeRule.onNodeWithTag(TestTags.PASSWORD_INPUT).performTextInput("P@ssw0rd")
    composeRule.onNodeWithText("Entrar").performClick()

    assertThat(navController.currentBackStackEntry?.destination?.route)
        .isEqualTo(AppScreens.Home.route)
}
```